# .NET Core build with dll reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to get .NET core to work with the build system at my work, which had been designed with Java in mind. But it is sadly so integrated into our pipelines that there is no way we can be without it. So if I want to use .NET at work will it have to be with this build system.

Each project is built into a package, with their own git repository.

Given a program like below where `MyConsoleApp` has a dependency on `MyLibrary`.

```
MyProgram-Solution
 - MyConsoleApp
 - MyLibrary
```

At build time the source code would be placed in

```
/build/packages/MyConsoleApp/
/build/packages/MyLibrary/
```

However I can only build one at the time, and I cannot move the source code.
Which means that I would need to build `MyLibrary` first, with the DLL ending up in

```
/build/packages/MyLibrary/out/MyLibrary.1.0.dll
```

When I then build MyConsoleApp, I need a way to tell the .NET Core build tool that the `MyLibrary.1.0.dll` file can be found at

```
/build/packages/MyLibrary/out/MyLibrary.1.0.dll
```

Storing packages in Nuget is not an option, as the package may not be ready for release at the build time, and the build system works in a sandbox mode, meaning it has no external connections.

I can edit the `MyConsoleApp.csproj` if that makes it possible.

Comment: You can use NuGet without an external connection. `MyLibrary` could build a package, then `MyConsoleApp` could use a `NuGet.config` file to add a folder on the build system as a NuGet package source - i.e. pull the NuGet package directly from `/build/packages/MyLibrary/out/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add assembly references using Visual Studio, same as with .NET Framework projects.

If you want to modify the project file by hand, you'll need something like the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="MyLibrary">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\MyLibrary\out\MyLibrary.1.0.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```